# Convert our internal userdetails implementation to Spring's User object

Tags: java, spring, jackson

I am getting `NoSuchMethodError` when I try to convert the Boolean field. I know I can convert boolean primitive but somehow I want to make it Boolean object so that whenever needed I can set it to null with the setter method.

```
UserDetails springUserRecord = new User(
userRecord.getUsername(), userRecord.getPassword(), userRecord.isDone);
```

So my isDone method in the UserDetails POJO class was primitive `boolean` and now I changed it to `Boolean`. Then when I ran the program I got the exception.

Class - `org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User`

How can I change the fields of this class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typecast it

```
UserDetails springUserRecord = new User(
userRecord.getUsername(), userRecord.getPassword(), (Boolean)userRecord.isDone);
```